# junit theories resolve to ParameterizedAssertionError instead of failure

Tags: java, junit, junit-theory

I run theories test like this

```
@Theory
public void qlIsNotNullAndReservationWithRefIdDoesntHaveItemReference(
        @TestedOn(ints = {100, 200, 300}) final int value) {

    assertTrue("should be no error", false);
}
```

It will always end up in ParameterizedAssertionError errors without any meaningful message.

As there anyway to show a "proper" failure with message?

Logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ stock ---
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to /Users/user/repository/reboot/trunk/company-stock/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ stock ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/user/repository/reboot/trunk/company-stock/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Running de.company.stock.webservice.CornerCaseAnalysisIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.265 sec <<< FAILURE!
test1(de.company.stock.webservice.CornerCaseAnalysisIT)  Time elapsed: 0.082 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: test1(ints)
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
        at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
        at de.company.stock.webservice.CornerCaseAnalysisIT.test1(CornerCaseAnalysisIT.java:60)


Results :

Tests in error: 
   ? ParameterizedAssertion test1(ints)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.763s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 20 17:57:56 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/989M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project stock: There are test failures.
```

Comment: Could you kindly publish ALL error log?

Comment: read the next edit, please.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

```
package com.junit.theory;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.suppliers.TestedOn;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryTry {

    @Theory
    public void tryTheory(
            @TestedOn(ints = {100, 200, 300}) final int point) {

        assertTrue("should be no error", false);
    }

}
```

The resulting trace is:

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: tryTheory(ints)
    at org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories$TheoryAnchor.reportParameterizedError(Theories.java:192)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: should be no error  <---LOOK HERE!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    ...
    at org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories$TheoryAnchor$1$1.evaluate(Theories.java:141)
    ... 20 more
```

And in Failure Trace window set to `Filtered` there are only three lines:

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: tryTheory(ints)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: should be no error  <---LOOK HERE!
at com.junit.theory.TheoryTry.tryTheory(TheoryTry.java:18)
```

As you can see, your message IS there. Do you have something different?

Comment: what if I rather interested why it failed not where? in my case in just says qlIsNotNullAndReservationWithRefIdDoesntHaveItemReference(ints). So I don't even see which datapoint failed.

Comment: If so, I would think that the problem is with "final".

Comment: Can't do anything about it. General code style in the company. Still I need to show a message with failure reason. The reason for that: one of methods may throw a run-time exception from db. I need to make sure to communicate this exception message to logs.

Comment: Nope, it is not because of datapoint list. removing assertion statement makes the test pass.

Comment: @Macchiatow If your function has no body, there will be no actions at all, due to optimalizaton. And of course, no substitutions for value and no errors.

Comment: The version I published is the shortest possible just to make a showcase. Original method has enough logic, moreover, implements logging so I see all values get applied (if no assert fails in between). And yes, I removed 'final' - no difference.

Comment: @Macchiatow And what about the result? Do you see your line "should be no error" in the error log? Don't you have the error log filtered?

Comment: No I don't have filter. and result as in my post. Doesn't give any information. At the same time running with @Test annotation works as expected

Comment: @Macchiatow  When you are looking at Failure Trace window (if you don't, open it), right click on any line and choose "Copy Trace". After that paste it in some text editor. It simply can't be so short - obviously, it is the problem of your IDE. Which one do you have? Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJIdea?

Comment: @Macchiatow. I am taking my hat off... But it seems, you really have shorten error log. IMHO, you should run or build the application with some parameters set so, that you'll see more of the error log. Also, the full error log could be written to some file. Your problem is NOT in Java or JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to JUnit 4.12. 
They fixed it in that release, 
look: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/607